# Randomizing values in Blender 3.0 Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

**TLWR:** How do I randomize any value in Geometry Nodes (Blender 3.0)

Some versions before the Geometry Nodes fields update there was a node labeled "Attribute Randomize" which randomized whichever value. But now in 3.0 that node isn't there anymore, and trying to randomize a value with the "Random Value" node results in an incompatible socket connection (*the connection to the Transform node turns red*).
[image: screenshot of my current problem]

For context, I'm trying to randomize rotation on some **instanced points**. I've tried finding a way to do it but no tutorial seems to go over those changes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, the *Transform* node doesn't support fields as inputs, only normal vectors. However, you can use this simple node group to transform objects based on fields:
[image]
Which then supports the output of the *Random Value* node.
[image]
For transforming individual instances, you can use the *Scale Instances*, *Rotate Instances* or *Translate Instances* nodes, which can easily be built into this node group:
[image]

Comment: Note that the order in which you apply the transforms is relevant, see : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/16721/142703 or https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/4194

Comment: I constructed your Transform Fields group node, but input from the Random Value node causes *each vertex* to be transformed randomly, when what I want is for the entire selection of geometry to be transformed together relative to a point (in this case, the object origin). Do you know what I should do differently?

Comment: I found the answer to my question! [It was answered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/254678/2952) in response to a different question I asked that *relates* to this one. Answer: Connecting a **Value** node's output socket to the **Random Value** node's **ID** input socket results in all verts being transformed uniformly by *a single* random value.

Answer (score 3):

How about to use *Translate Instances* node? I added the node after a *Instance on Points* node, and connected a *Random Value* node to *Translation* of the *Translate Instance* node.

For more details, please see following figure.
[image: Example of Translate Instances node]
( Input mesh is a cube with 8 vertices. )

### Update

I found the other method that is to add *Set Position*
node before *Instance on Points* node, and a *Random Value* node connects to *Offset* of the *Set Position* node.

[image: A method of using Set Position node]
( Input mesh is a cube of 8 vertices. )

I think this method is suited for many manipulations. For example, the method is easy to change point's Z-axis value according to input mesh's positions with sine function.

[image: Other manipulation]
( Input mesh is a plane, and added a modifier of *Subdivision* (Setting to simple and *Levels Viewport* is 4. )

Inspired by [Youtube Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qWnRRkV9Zk) and [Youtube Video 2](https://youtu.be/Qva1MzGtNC8)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I'm very new to the geometry nodes but this worked fine to me. For the "Random Value" node you have to drag from the ID and setup the right kind of data-type you're going for in addition to setting the "Vector/Float/Integer" data-type in the top of the node.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Be wary I have no clue what I'm doing!

Comment: avoid such comments as this doesn't make you credible.