# Geometry Nodes: Why doesn't this simple randomize scale work?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to randomize the x scale of an object and for some reason this setup doesn't work (Blender 3.0 released version).

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245008/randomizing-values-in-blender-3-0-geometry-nodes

Comment: Are you trying to randomize the scale of the faces of a *single object*, or the scale of object *instances*? With GN this is important to specify as each will have very different answers to the question. Please try to make this a little clearer in your question with an [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/248721/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround. apparently you need instances to use the random value node.
I have no idea why. This will give you the same result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works :-) Turns out the particle system uses the exact same instance, so there's still no variation. Thanks though, helped a lot!

Comment: @chippwalters If you want to use instances as workaround, please use the nodes `Geometry to Instance` and `Translate Instances` instead (cleaner solution).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding value node. It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: ...This is the correct way this task should be solved (except maybe that you should use an integer value instead of float).

Comment: Thanks. Yes. Integer is more suitable here.