# How can I change binary numbers from from top to bottom?

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, instances

I created a plane and subdivided it 49 times to create a decent amount of vertices.

I did this to instance the numbers 0 and 1 along each point to create a binary animation that randomly changes
numbers across the entire plane.

Now I'm going for, and can't seem to figure out, how to make them randomly change in a pattern. For example, what if I made the top row of numbers randomly change, then row 2 (under row 1) changes, then row 3, etc. So essentially if there are 10 rows, only one is randomly changing at a time as it makes its way down the plane.

I've tried driving textures to affect only one part at a time, but unfortunately, no success. I'm still new to geo-nodes, so that could be why.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot or sketch how it should look like? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no time right now to work on this... but maybe I can help with some "inspiration". In my answer to another question I explained how random values are bound to seed and the IDs of points. So it might be that in combination with seed and id you can try to find a way to select specific parts that should be affected. Here's my explanation: [Random values connected to ID](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/254678/99859)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a shader-only approach.

For this we'll need an Indexed Grid, which is a handy little group to have around, anyway:

[image]

It wraps the texture-space into cells, gives each cell its own UV, and an X,Y index: the coordinates of the cell's own UV origin:

[image]

Once you have the index, you can use it as an input UV, to pixellate any texture:

[image]

Above, It's pixellating noise. It's then put through a threshold, yielding black/white, and, in turn, that's used as a mask between  a '0' texture and a '1' texture:

[image]

Above, that's done twice, with two different noise textures, to produce two separate arrangements of '1' and '0'.

Those separate arrangements can then be mixed together using any function you want of the cell index. Here, it's a function which converts the X and Y of the index into a serial number, starting at the bottom left and finishing at the top-right:

[image]

... but the wipe between the arrangements could equally be by (cell-index Y), giving a row-by-row change.. included in this .blend.

[image]

Comment: Wow, nice version, too +1

Comment: Love your ignoring of his tags ❣️❣️❣️

Comment: @Chris Oops! ... Well. OP _did_ mention they had tried textures and they didn't work.. that's license, in my book :)

Comment: @RobinBetts I'd say, if someone tried textures and only switched to GN because it seems impossible with textures, then you're fully licensed to show it is possible 

Comment: Thanks so much for this. As a noob, I have to ask what node that is in the first image? The one that says "scale"?

Comment: @circleofsorrow1 It's a _Vector Math_ node set to _Scale_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks so much, you're brilliant.

Answer (score 5):

There might be more elegant solutions but this is just a quick example how it could be achieved. I've subdivided my plane fewer times, but the principle works with your high resolution as well.

I'm looking top down on the plane, so I wanted to change the rows from Y to -Y. For that I used a *Separate XYZ* node and checked the Y value if it's *Less Than* a certain value, which is animated from from a positive value down to a negative value. The result "no" (0) or "yes" is then plugged into the *Seed* input of a *Random Value* node, basically making the setup switch the the seed from 0 to 1 going down the Y axis.

Of course this setup can be tweaked and manipulated to switch between other seeds etc. and maybe there are better solutions. But here's how it looks as is now:

[image: random animation]

I guess there are other ways to switch the output text better and the other thing is, if you would use *Mesh Primitives* > *Grid* inside *Geometry Nodes* there might also be a way to select via IDs and so on. As I said, this is just to give you an idea what's possible. Here's the node setup:

[image: node setup]

Comment: I guessed someone such as you would go for a perfectly good GN approach (.. if you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail..) so I ducked the other way :D

Comment: @RobinBetts Haha, thanks but I'm still a bloody beginner with Geometry Nodes, especially since they are still changing a lot between versions 